# Make root domain 301 redirect to A while specific page redirects to B in nginx

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I'm using nginx and I have a domain that redirects to a specific URL like so:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
return 301 http://example.net/page/example;
}
```

That works great, but now I want to add an additional URL redirect. I also want `example.com/coolstory` to redirect to `http://bro.example.net/dumb/bloated?=address`

So, in summary, I want:

```
example.com -> http://example.net/page/example
example.com/coolstory -> http://bro.example.net/dumb/bloated?=address
```

I tried adding this to the server directive above, but it just gets ignored.

```
location /coolstory([0-9]+) {
return 301 bro.example.net/dumb/bloated?=address;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a bit of tinkering around, but I figured it out myself.

```
server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     server_name example.com www.example.com;
     location /index.html {
          return 301 http://example.net/page/example;
     }
     location /coolstory {
          return 301 http://bro.example.net/dumb/bloated?=address;
     }
}
```

I removed the server-level 301 redirect, and referred to the root domain by `/index.html` as apposed to just `/`, which didn't work. Of course index.html doesn't actually exist, so it feels suboptimal, but it works and it's better than an html redirect.